# Need help pulling rows where member bought more than 6 units per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to run a pull that counts the UNITS from a MEMBER and only show the rows where the member passes 6 in units. (So everything after 6 units would get pulled based on the date). Every month the member is only allowed to buy 6 in quantity.  How do I pull the only LOGS where the member exceeded 6 units?

The units in the where clause will not pull the recent rows after the 6th quantity is passed.

```
Select *
from LogTable where [item] in ('Candy','drinks','meat')
and [units] > 6  ;
```

[image]

Comment: Group and sum the unit by member and month, join this back to the same table to get the rest of the data. After you're done learning how that worked, look at `SUM(units) OVER(PARTITION BY member, YEAR(date), MONTH(date))`.. Then upgrade the OVER clause  with a `ORDER BY date) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to get a rolling count of how much they spent as a rolling total with each transaction, and look for those rows > 6 on the rolling total

Comment: Ok working on this now

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below:

```
SELECT SUM(Units), Member FROM LogTable WHERE [item] in ('Candy','drinks','meat')
GROUP BY Member
HAVING SUM(Units)>6
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what I talked about in the comments:

```
WITH x AS(
  SELECT 
    lt.*,
    SUM(lt.[units]) OVER(PARTITION BY lt.[member], YEAR(lt.[date]), MONTH(lt.[date]) ORDER BY lt.[date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as rolling_total
  FROM LogTable lt 
  WHERE lt.[item] in ('Candy','drinks','meat')
)

SELECT * FROM x WHERE rolling_total > 6;
```

ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is the default action when a SUM OVER has an ORDER BY, but I find it helps prompt to remember how to change it or use it elsewhere for other things. The full clause is actually `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` - you can imagine how you can use other specs if you want a sliding window e.g. the number of purchases in the previous N trips not including the current.. (rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding)

Note, I wasn't really clear on if it's 6 units of anything or 6 units of candy, and 6 units of emat etc per member. If it's per food type, yu'll ahve to add `[item]` to the PARTITION too

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM(
    SELECT
        Member,
        MONTH(Date) AS 'Month',
        SUM(UNITS) AS 'SUM'
    FROM LogTable
    WHERE in ('Candy','drinks','meat') 
    GROUP BY 
        Member,
        MONTH(Date) AS 'Month')z
    WHERE SUM > 6
```